# Aggregate functions with more than one join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this simple example to count how many quotes per account I have

```
SELECT 
A.accountId, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Q.QuoteId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as NumberOfQuotes
FROM Account A 
LEFT JOIN Quote Q ON A.AccountId = Q.AccountId
WHERE A.accountid = '58B3F89E-E1E5-E511-B1F5-4ED0FE97D338'
GROUP BY A.AccountId
```

This gives 9 which is correct.

If I then want to show how many quotes and how many orders an account has I tried this:

```
SELECT 
A.accountId, 
SUM(CASE WHEN Q.QuoteId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as NumberOfQuotes,
SUM(CASE WHEN P.new_propid IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as NumberOfOrders
FROM Account A 
LEFT JOIN Quote Q ON A.AccountId = Q.AccountId
LEFT JOIN new_prop P ON A.AccountId = P.New_accountid
WHERE A.accountid = '58B3F89E-E1E5-E511-B1F5-4ED0FE97D338'
GROUP BY A.AccountId
```

This gives 18 for both figures, which is wrong.

Obviously i'm doing this wrong. Is it possible to do multiple aggregates/joins like this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DISTINCT` instead:

```
SELECT A.accountId,
       COUNT(DISTINCT Q.QuoteId) AS NumberOfQuotes,
       COUNT(DISTINCT P.new_propid) AS NumberOfOrders
FROM Account A
     LEFT JOIN Quote Q ON A.AccountId = Q.AccountId
     LEFT JOIN new_prop P ON A.AccountId = P.New_accountid
WHERE A.accountid = '58B3F89E-E1E5-E511-B1F5-4ED0FE97D338'
GROUP BY A.AccountId;
```

Also, note you don't need to use a `CASE` expression with a `SUM` along the lines of `SUM(CASE WHEN Q.QuoteId IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)`. Aggregate expressions automatically ignore `NULL` values; unless you have `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, but that's highly unrecommended:

[SET ANSI_NULLS (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-ansi-nulls-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> In a future version of SQL Server, ANSI_NULLS will be ON and any
>   applications that explicitly set the option to OFF will generate an
>   error. Avoid using this feature in new development work, and plan to
>   modify applications that currently use this feature.